# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch on deleteview

Tags: python, django

I am deleting a post using generic DeleteView. On clicking the link for delete it returns

> **django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch**: Reverse for 'postdelete' with
>   no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   `['posts/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/delete/$']`

I tried placing the  before and after /delete/

```
#urls.py
path('posts/<int:id>/delete/',blogpostDelete.as_view(),name='postdelete'),

#DeleteView
class blogpostDelete(DeleteView):
    success_url='/posts/'   
    template_name="blog/delete.html"
    def get(self,request,id) :
        Blogpost = get_object_or_404(blogpost,id=id)
        return self.render_to_response({'id':id})

#link in template
<a href={% url "postdelete" id=id %}>Delete</a>

#delete.html
{% block content %}

<form action={% url "postdelete" %} method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete "{{ id }}"?</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Where did you define a `urlpattern` with name `postdelete`?

Comment: in urls.py see first line of code

Comment: @anon-bee-01 question: your delete URL is loading the delete form?
I mean the form is being submitted to the same url it's open into?

Comment: @xxbinxx the delete URL is loading the delete form from the post detail page and returning to all posts

Comment: so as "gurmukh singh" answered you don't need to have `action`, by default your form will be submitted to the same url it's loaded from (which is `posts/<id>/delete/`). Once the request hit your `delete` view, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: @anon-bee-01 were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing `id` to the url.

Try something like this

```
<form action={% url "postdelete" id="{{id}}" %} method="post">
```

Comment: I tried this <form action={% url "postdelete" id=id %} method="post"> the delete form was loaded but when i clicked on delete, same error is coming. also now im getting same error if i open any post

Comment: Can you inspect and check what's the value of action attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

In Delete View No need to pass id in html form action
Doing Like this:

```
 <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>Are you sure you want to delete "{{ id }}"?</p>
        <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
    </form>
```